# How do you solve for the cardinality of a power set of some complex set? (i.e. $|\mathcal P(A^n)|$ , $|\mathcal P(A\cup B)|$ )

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, cardinals

**Suppose** $A$ is some set such that $A = \{a_1,a_2,\dotsb,a_n\}$.

We know that $|A|=n$.

We know that $\mathcal P(A)=  2^n$.

**Now** let $A^n$ denote the cartesian product of a set A with itself n times.
$$\text{(i.e.) }\left[A^n=\underbrace{A\times A\times\dotsb\times A}_\text{$n$}\right]$$

We know the cartesian product of a sets $A\times B=|A|*|B|$

**Thus** $|A^n| = \left[\underbrace{|A|* |A|*\dotsb*|A|}_\text{$n$}\right] = |A|^n$

**???** $|\mathcal P(A^n)|=\dots$

---

### Question:

- What is a general way to solve for the cardinality of a *power set* of some complex set equation?
- If there are general steps for finding the cardinality of a *power set* of some complex set equation, what are they?
- Is $|\mathcal P(A^n)| = 2^{n^n} =2$^n^n?

Comment: It is $2^{(|A|^n)}$

Comment: A very minor note: be careful when saying $|A|=n$ because that is only true if $a_i\neq a_j$ for all $i\neq j$. I know you probably implied that this was the case for $A$ but it helps to be pedantic when working with this stuff.

Comment: The definition I use for a set does not include repetition of elements. There is another construction deduced from the cartesian product of a set (taking the quotient by the symmetric group permuting the coordinates) this gives a set "the symmetric product" where elements are sets in which repetition is permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know that $|\mathcal P(X)|=2^{|X|}$.

If $X=n^n$ then $|\mathcal P(X)|=2^{n^n}$. And indeed if $|A|=n$ and $X=A^n$, then $|X|=n^n$.

Generally speaking, finding the cardinality of the power set requires you to find the cardinality of $X$, if $X$ is a union, or product or whatever, then you need to calculate the cardinality of this $X$, and take $2^{|X|}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of any subset of a set $Y \subseteq X$ as a binary string, where each character represents an element of $X$ and is $1$ or $0$ if the element is in $Y$ or is not in $Y$ respectively, you find out that all the distinct binary strings of "length" $|X|$ are in 1-1 correspondence with all the distinct subsets of $X$. We know the elements of $ \mathcal P \left({X}\right) $ are all the subsets of $X$, and we also know the number of binary strings of "length" $|X|$ is $2^{|X|}$, so:
$$ |\mathcal P \left({X}\right)| = 2^{|X|} $$
For any set $X$ (finite or not).